# Intellij Idea Comment Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, comments

I am trying to compile a piece of code that has the following line comment in IntelliJ Idea:

// a char can be written in unicode (just add \u before)

and I'm getting the following error code at compile time: Error:(23, 55) java: Invalid unicode. If I remove the backslash character before "u", everything works fine. I don't understand how or why a comment can create compile time errors. Eclipse doesn't have this problem.

Comment: You mention Eclipse doesn't have the same problem. That is most likely because of the Eclipse _compiler_. I just typed your comment into Intellij verbatim and the _editor_ shows no error. It is _javac_ that shows the error. However, the Eclipse compiler can compile even if there are compile time errors. Instead, you'll get an error at _runtime_ saying something like `Unresolved compilation problem`. The error occurs when Java attempts to execute that part of the code.This allows you to run part of your code even though another part fails to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by adding a space char after the backslash.

```
// a char can be written in unicode (just add \ u before)
```

Comment: Seems to be working. I still don't understand why a comment is being parsed for escape characters (if that is what's been happening).

Comment: @Slaw Thanks, that explains it.